# Multi-row text in heading

Tags: c++, mfc, grid-layout, ultimategrid

I'm working on a complex grid layout, and UltimateGrid is my choice.

I have set a **multi-row heading**, then I have **joined some cells in heading vertically**.

Now, I'm looking for a way to set multi-line text in heading cells which I have joined.

Here's an explanatory screenshot.

[image: explanatory screenshot]

I already have tried by writing:

```
void MyCug::OnSetup(){

int rows = 5;
int cols = 20;

// setup rows and columns
SetNumberRows(rows);
SetNumberCols(cols);

// create 3 row top heading
SetTH_NumberRows(2);

...

JoinCells (16, -2, 16, -1); // Here I joins - in heading - two cells : row 16, columns -2 and -1

...

// Then I retrieve merged cell
CUGCell m_cell;
GetCell(16, -2, &m_cell);

// I need to show multi-line content in heading cells: I tried to set multi-row property.
int result = m_cell.SetPropertyFlags(m_cell.GetPropertyFlags() | UGCELL_MULTIROWCELL);

if (result == UG_SUCCESS) {
    bool ok = true;     // all seems to be ok...
}

m_cell.SetText("string\r\nstring\r\nstring"); // Despite my attempt, this will be always show on a single line!
SetCell(16, -3, &m_cell);

...
}
```

Without success: cell text is always shown on a single line, that is exactly what I don't want.

How can I get the cell text on multiple lines?

Comment: depending on how the control is implemented the code for Carriage Return / Line Feed could be either `\r\n`, `\n\r`, or `\n`. Try them all in a row and see which one works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tell how I have solved my problem, hoping it will be useful to someone.

To set multi-line cells, member function **CUGCell::SetCellTypeEx()** should be used.
This function allow you to set extended properties for single cells.

The example below works perfectly:

```
void MyCug::OnSetup(){

int rows = 5;
int cols = 20;

// setup rows and columns
SetNumberRows(rows);
SetNumberCols(cols);

// create 3 row top heading
SetTH_NumberRows(2);

...

JoinCells (16, -2, 16, -1); // Here i joins - in heading - two cells : row 16, columns -2 and -1

...

// I retrieve merged cell
CUGCell m_cell;
GetCell(16, -2, &m_cell);

cell.SetCellTypeEx(UGCT_NORMALMULTILINE); // set multiline cell

m_cell.SetText("string\r\nstring\r\nstring");

SetCell(16, -3, &m_cell);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `OnSetup()` method:

1. Set the number of rows in the top heading.

```
SetTH_NumberRows(2); // Set 2 rows
```

2. Join the range of cells together

```
JoinCells(1,-2, 1,-1); // Join row -1 and -2 in column 1
```

3. Add multiline feature to the cell

```
QuickSetCellTypeEx(1, -2, UGCT_NORMALMULTILINE); // Column 1, row -2 is a multiline
```

4. Add text

```
CString title = _T("New\r\nline");
QuickSetText(1, -2, title); SetColWidth(1, 200); // Set text in the preferred cell
```